# ZFS script pull latest snapshot and restore

Tags: linux, text-processing, scripting, zfs

I keep my zfs snapshot backups in `zfs/snapshotbackps` and my virtual machghines run off direct `zfs` location

I am trying to create a script that will pull the latest snapshot and restore it.

I've tried the following

```
machine=582
zfs list -o name -s creation -t snapshot | grep "zfs/snapshotbackps/vm-${machine}-" |tail -n1 | xargs zfs send | "zfs receive zfs/vm-${machine}-disk-0"
```

Which returns

```
-bash: zfs receive zfs/vm-582-disk-0: No such file or directory
xargs: zfs: terminated by signal 13
```

What is wrong, the data is there

```
zfs list -o name -s creation -t snapshot | grep "zfs/snapshotbackps/vm-${machine}-" |tail -n1
zfs/snapshotbackps/vm-582-disk-0@ZAP_HOME1_2023-05-19T10:26:19p0100--1w
```

Answer (score 3):

Your quoting is flawed.  Try something like:

```
machine="582"
snap="$(zfs list -o name -s creation -t snapshot |
   grep "zfs/snapshotbackps/vm-${machine}-" |
   tail -n1)"
zfs send "$snap" | zfs receive "zfs/vm-${machine}-disk-0"
```

Your original syntax may work if you remove the quotes around the `zfs receive`.  The error message you're receiving is the same message that you'd get if you typed:

```
$ "echo foo"
bash: echo foo: command not found
```

You might also consider doing a `zfs rollback` on the original `zfs/vm-582-disk-0` filesystem.  It should be quite a bit faster.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you.